Geoprocessing outputs no longer appearing in selected folder, appear at top of Layers pane
I recently upgraded from QGIS 3.28.10 (Firenze) to 3.34.5 (Prizren). I'm noticing that the results of geoprocessing do not appear in the selected folder or above the selected layer in the Layers pane. They appear by default at the top of the Layers pane. Does anyone know if this is a setting that can be adjusted, or if this is a regression between versions?
3.34.5 (Prizren) - Undesired behaviour

3.22.1 (Firenze) - Desired behaviour

